# Connect with a TCP Server running into VMWare where network type is NAT

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, network-programming, nat

I have C# TCP Server program which is running into VMWare and network type is NAT. There TCP server works as a http server, so that I can connect it using browser. Now when I am connecting it using this url **http://localhost:33333/OrderDetails**, it works without any problem. But when I am trying to connect it from outside of VMWare using this link **http://1.39.37.243:33333/OrderDetails** **(1.39.37.243 is my PC's public ip)**, then its not working. I can't change the network type NAT, because my customer's office Network system is also NAT system. Where am I doing it wrong ? Any thoughts or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain how/why you are expecting this to work? How are you expecting the PC to know to send the TCP packets to the VM?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Customer will run this application into a Nat System. And Customers clients will access this application from outside of NAT system. For testing purpose I am using the VM.

Comment: Is this a "how do I do this" question or a "why isn't this working" question? Do you think it should work with just what you've done? Or do you think that you haven't done anything to make this work?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - this is a "why isn't this working" question. And after spend some time on searching, I found a way to do this, though in that case I wont use it as http server. The way is the 'Teamviewer' way, UDP Hole punching. This the only way found that can send data over NAT system.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't working because the machine receiving the TCP packets has no reason to forward them to the VM. In other words, this isn't working because you haven't done anything to make it work.

You need to [configure VMWare's NAT](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_nat_advanced.html) to forward these incoming TCP connections to the VM.

You could also have other problems:

1. The server might not be listening on the right IP address. For example, if the listening socket is bound to localhost, only localhost connections will work.
2. There might be something else in the path keeping the TCP packets from getting to the host. For example, if the host itself is behind NAT, port forwarding may need to be configured in the router.
3. Port forwarding won't work from inside the LAN unless the router supports hairpinning. If the host itself is behind NAT, test from outside the LAN after setting up port forwarding in the router.

Comment: An additional case can be *"the blockade by the firewall on the VM side"*!